# How to mock fields of inner singleton objects?

Tags: scala, mockito, inner-classes, scalatest, mockito-scala

Given the following code snippet

```
class Config {
  private val conf = ConfigFactory.load()

  object Http {
    val host = conf.getString("http.host")
    val port = conf.getInt("http.port")
  }
}
```

how can `host` and `port` fields of inner singleton object `Http` be mocked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[mockito-scala](https://github.com/mockito/mockito-scala) provides `ReturnsDeepStubs` via `IdiomaticMockito`

```
import org.mockito.stubbing.ReturnsDeepStubs
import org.mockito.{ArgumentMatchersSugar, IdiomaticMockito}

val config = mock[Config](ReturnsDeepStubs)
config.Http.host returns "www.example.com"
config.Http.port returns 80
```

Without deep stubbing we could do

```
import org.scalatest.mockito.MockitoSugar
import org.mockito.Mockito.when    

val config = mock[Config]
val httpConfig = mock[config.Http.type]
when(httpConfig.host).thenReturn("www.example.com")
when(httpConfig.port).thenReturn(80)
when(config.Http).thenReturn(httpConfig)
```