# Deep stubbing in Scala

Tags: scala, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I am facing to mock nested function problem in Scala context. I have found answer like this:
[How to mock fields of inner singleton objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48592974/how-to-mock-fields-of-inner-singleton-objects) which works but isn't concise. I am wondering in Scala community is there something like mockito's deepstub?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ReturnsDeepStubs` from [mockito-scala](https://github.com/mockito/mockito-scala). Here is a working example

```
import org.mockito.stubbing.ReturnsDeepStubs
import org.mockito.{ArgumentMatchersSugar, IdiomaticMockito}
import org.scalatest.flatspec.AnyFlatSpec
import org.scalatest.matchers.should.Matchers

trait Bar {
  def zar: Int
}
trait Foo {
  def bar: Bar
}

class MockitoScalaDeepStubExampleSpec extends AnyFlatSpec with Matchers with IdiomaticMockito with ArgumentMatchersSugar {
  "mockito-scala" should "provide deep stubs" in {
    val foo = mock[Foo](ReturnsDeepStubs)
    foo.bar.zar returns 42
    foo.bar.zar should be (42)
  }
}
```

Comment: Having to mock the response of a mocked object shows why mocking isn't really a good idea never and that your design is more coupled that it should.